# C# Events not being raised

Tags: c#, visual-studio, event-handling

So I am trying to learn events and I've done all that's needed to be done to Raise and listen to a simple event, but I am getting no feedback at all when I run the code. The event is simply ignored and only the Hello world is computed. I have two classes, one is a simple Car class, the other an Owner class.

In the car class, I create the event and Raise it according to how the documentation by microsoft says.
In the owner class, I listen to it via calling function and then subscribing to it. Still, nothing happens. Please help, i'm about to give up on this.

```
//--------CAR CLASS-----//


using System;

namespace EventsTutorial

{
    public class Car
    {
        public event EventHandler<int> CarOnEvent;

        

        public Car(string name, string colour, int id)
        {
            Name = name;
            Colour = colour;
            IsOn = false;
            Id = id;
            TurnOn(id);
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Colour { get; set; }
        public bool IsOn { get; private set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        protected virtual void TurnOn(int e)
        {
            EventHandler<int> handler = CarOnEvent;
            handler?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
//-----------OWNER CLASS-------------
using System;

namespace EventsTutorial
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" World!");

            Car mycar = new Car("Toyota", "Black", 1);
            mycar.CarOnEvent += Mycar_CarOnEvent;
            
        }

      

        private static void Mycar_CarOnEvent(object sender, int e)
        {
            Car var = (Car)sender;

            Console.WriteLine("The car {0}, is now on", var.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, check out the msdn guidelines concerning events and naming and so on:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/event

Comment: And this should be of interest aswell - https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `TurnOn` in the `Car` constructor, before anyone is attached to the event.

You must first attach to the event and then call `TurnOn`.

```
//New car constructor...
public Car(string name, string colour, int id)
{
    Name = name;
    Colour = colour;
    IsOn = false;
    Id = id;
}

//New TurnOn
protected virtual void TurnOn()
{
    EventHandler<int> handler = CarOnEvent;
    handler?.Invoke(this, this.Id);
}

//New main...
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" World!");

    Car mycar = new Car("Toyota", "Black", 1);
    mycar.CarOnEvent += Mycar_CarOnEvent;
    myCar.TurnOn()
}
```

Comment: Ah this is what I was getting at too.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! But I am confused as to why. How come it works when we subscribe to the event, before calling?

In my head, you can't listen to something that hadn't been called yet. Is this how it works?

Cause if I call TurnOn method, then put the subscribe, it doesn't run

Comment: @SentryCOD Nope, it works the other way around. An event is nothing more than syntactical sugar around delegates, when you subscribe to an event it creates a delegate (or composite delegate but that's other history) that points to the attached function, then when you raise that event what you are doing is nothing else than invoke the delegate what will execute the pointed function, if there's no function to call, it does nothing. Hope this clarifies it a bit for you :)